# Allow for a comment when undeleting

Tags: feature-request

I was viewing a question today where there was one active and accepted answer, and there was one deleted answer.

The deleted answer (in my opinion) is more useful that the non-deleted answer. So I flagged it for undelete.

The problem I see here is: what motivation is there for anybody else (including the OP) to also want to undelete the post?

I feel that if I was able to add a comment, saying something like "This answer should be undeleted because it is more useful than the accepted answer" would prompt the OP (and other users) to want to undelete the answer.

Comment: So why not just attribute your answer to the original answerer? *"A shown in a deleted answer by @Username...."* ?

Comment: At the moment casting an undelete vote will put the post in the [recent undelete votes](http://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=delete&daterange=last7days) in the 10k tools - although - I'm not sure how many people either know it exists or look at it.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Perhaps I shouldn't have mentioned a work around.. I don't want to discus how to copy somebody elses answer. I want to try and improve the feature of undeleting posts. Take for example if it was a question, not an answer, I don't think it would make sense to copy the question and ask my own...

Comment: @JonClements: No idea that existed, I did look in the 'review' section before hand to see if there was a queue for them. Again, I think it would be useful for reviewers to see a reason for the undelete flag to help them review it more accurately

Comment: @JonClements - I'm curious, is there a link somewhere to that `/tools` url? i've never that page before..

Comment: @Sayse go to "review" in the navbar, then at the top (above the list of review queues) there's actually two tabs (it defaults to "Review"): Tools | Review... click "Tools"...

Comment: @JonClements - Oh wow... I never knew that was a clickable link - I always just assumed it was some sort of (text only) breadcrumb I guess, thanks

Comment: I'm not sure being able to leave a comment on a deleted post (which is currently mod only and has slightly different behaviour than normal) would really help much - the largest scope it'd have is the OP and perhaps the last user (or specific user if `@`d) as by nature it doesn't bump the post - eg: it'd still require more users to come across the post *somehow* to consider it for undeletion (which could be a more obvious review queue instead of something nested in the 10k tools, but I'm fairly sure that has been requested before and been declined).

Comment: @JonClements: Well the OP being able to see the comment is great for starters. That would be the fastest way to get it undeleted, and it is much better for the OP to understand why the undelete vote has been cast, rather than trying to guess. Other than OP, sure people have to find it *somehow*  but what happen now is nobody will understand why the undelete vote exists. A simple comment explaining why just makes it a lot clearer for everybody. Imagine in a comment "this is the only answer that actually works"... is it not in our best interests to ensure that answer is recovered?

Comment: To be honest, most of the time I don't even want to vote for undelete. I would much rather just be able to leave a comment for the OP saying "You should consider undeleting this because..."

Comment: IDK if wee need a delete queue (it could be nice) but this kinda stuff makes me wish there was an undelete queue.