# How to comment on vote for undelete

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions

So I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893455), putting in a fair amount of work.

It was marked a duplicate, but none of the referenced questions addressed the first question the OP asked.

And then the question was subsequently deleted, despite the presence of a well-received answer that actually addressed the OP's questions.

I've voted to undelete, but I'd like to add a comment to future reviewers about why I'm voting to undelete -- it's not a duplicate.

Is that feasible?

Comment: nope. you can't do that.

Comment: You can't really comment on it anywhere but Meta.  That said, I do feel like value was lost by having your answer deleted.  I've cast an undelete vote as well.

Comment: i mean, it's just regurgitating documentation.

Comment: @Makoto Yeah, I mean just having multiple duplicates that answer the question isn't enough, we need to have that same information repeated over and over again so that...because...reasons?

Comment: @Servy:  While the duplicates answer *one* facet of the original question, Andy's answer answers *all* facets of the original question, including other details on what arrays actually *are*.  If you can find a duplicate to cover as much ground as that, I'll gladly withdraw my argument, but until then, I truly do think that deletion of this was in haste.

Comment: @KevinB - The answer is *citing* documentation.

Comment: The original question asks multiple questions, all of which are dupes. Does the fact that it asks multiple questions make it ineligible to be a dupe? that's absurd.

Comment: @Makoto The duplicates cover all of the information in the answer (and of course, as mentioned, the answer is only ever repeating the information from the official docs), so all of that info is already in two places.  We don't need a third.

Comment: OP: "Is int[] a class?" -- as far as I can tell, this is not addressed by the questions cited as duplicates.

Comment: @AndyThomas A direct quote of the first duplicate: `Arrays are special objects in java, they have a simple attribute named length which is final.

There is no "class definition" of an array (you can't find it in any .class file), they're a part of the language itself.`

Comment: @Servy:  Perhaps you misunderstand me.  I'm not necessarily contesting the fact that this is a duplicate.  However, I still contend that value was very much lost by having this answer removed.

Comment: @Makoto So why do you feel that repeating information that's already readily accessible is valuable?

Comment: @Servy - It takes a bit of a mental leap from "no class definition" to "not a class." And that doesn't really help the user understand the distinction between types and classes.

Comment: @Servy:  You seem to think that having duplicates around is a cancer of sorts, whereas *some* duplicates are okay.  I believe that this is firmly on the camp of an acceptable duplicate to keep around, however you seem to disagree.  I'll leave it at that; I don't have the luxury of time to argue about it right now.

Comment: @AndyThomas You're more than welcome to continue reading the rest of the answer, in which it specifically explains how arrays *are* categorized, and how it's a separate category from classes.

Comment: @Servy - You must be referring to a different answer than you quoted earlier.

Comment: @Makoto Duplicate questions are useful when they improve the visibility of the information in the question.  They have nothing at all to do with the answers.  You haven't argued that the question is phrased in a way that makes it findable in a way that other existing resources with the information aren't, you're simply saying that it's useful to have an answer that just duplicates information already readily accessible, which simply isn't the type of duplication that's valuable.  In fact, it's explicitly the type of duplication that *isn't* valuable.  This isn't an opinion.  This is policy.

Comment: And now someone is in punitive mode, downvoting the question, the answer, and Makato's accurate answer below. The negativity and reprisals are not creating an environment that encourages answering questions.

Comment: If the answer is worth keeping, request a merge. the question isn't worth keeping.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343477/allow-for-a-comment-when-undeleting

Comment: @AndyThomas The question is not a quality question; it's not useful.  The answer isn't useful either.  You're quite right that having an environment where low quality content has feedback indicating it's not quality content discourages people from continuing to provide said low quality content.  That is of course by design.  We want to encourage people to provide *valuable* content instead.

Comment: @Servy - I disagree with your value assessment. I recognize that it's useful to have rules in a game. But I also recognize that some players can make a game no longer fun.

Comment: Of course you do, you're the OP.

Comment: @AndyThomas SO isn't a game.  It's not here to entertain you.  It's here to provide useful reference content for the programming community at large.  That you went around trying to play a game and aren't having fun providing content that's not useful isn't a problem with SO.

Comment: @Servy - From Jeff Atwood, one of the creators of stackoverflow: https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-gamification/

Comment: @AndyThomas Including certain game-*like* elements in something that's *not a game* doesn't make it a game, and it doesn't mean that your personal enjoyment is the sole, or primary, purpose of SO.  Yes, SO includes *certain game related mechanics* to hopefully help the site accomplish it's *actual* goal of creating a useful repository of knowledge, but it's a means to an end, not the end in itself.  That blog post goes over all of that; it's a good read too.

Comment: Yeah. I'm not claiming that it's a game, or that it exists for my personal amusement. I'm using the game metaphor in a gamified system to explain why the negative experience is harmful to the goals. I'm done with this thread. Continue as you wish.

Comment: @AndyThomas The whole point of gamification (as SO uses it) is to reward good behavior and penalize bad behavior, so that people are incentivised to engage in good behavior and not in bad behavior.  That you're not having fun when doing something bad is *in line with what gamification is trying to do*.  If you were having lots of fun posting answers that weren't helpful then *that would be a bad thing*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is no way to specify the reason that you're casting an undelete vote.  These happen as anonymously as any other kind of voting here.

That said, if you do feel that the deletion of a post was in error, then there's no harm in bringing it to the attention of Meta.

Answer (score 1):

If you are elected as a moderator (or get moderation privileges as a result of becoming an SE staff member) then you'll be able to comment on deleted posts.  Until that happens, you can't.